# Passing Apollo Client cache data with apollo Query

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-link-state

I have two queries:

```
const GET_FILTERS = gql`
  query getFilters {
    filters @client {
      id
      title
      selected
    }
  }
`
```

And

```
const GET_POSTS = gql`
  query getPosts {
    posts {
      id
      author
      status
    }
  }
`
```

First one fetches the data from a local state using `apollo-link-state` and the second one is a external call.

I have a HOC for fetching posts setup like this:

```
const withPosts = (Component) => (props) => (
  <Query
    query={GET_POSTS}  
  >
    {({loading, data, error})} => {
      if(loading) return null
      if(error) return null
      return <Component {...data} {...props}/>
    }}
  </Query>
)
```

The fetching of the posts is fine but what I would like to do is to add whatever is returned from `GET_FILTERS` query with every call to `GET_POSTS` query?

One thing I could do is to wrap `withPost` in to another, lets say `withFilters` HOC, and pass the result in to `GET_POSTS` query as variables but I have been wondering if there is any other way to access that data via some sort of context and for example `cache.readQuery` using only `withPost` HOC.

Comment: What if you make a refetch query with the content of the previous one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apollo has 'native' tools for [HOC pattern](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#graphql), you can [compose](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#compose) many (named) queries and mutations to enhance component. IMHO it's much more readable and powerfull than using query/mutaions components.

You can pass queried (filter) values as variables via [data.fetchMore](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#graphql-query-data-fetchMore) - of course you can use query component for 'inner query'.

Using cache directly isn't required while query ['cache-first' fetchPolicy](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#graphql-config-options-fetchPolicy) option can be used.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. After a bit of research I totally agree with you that the composition is a way to go. Would you be able to enhance your answer with example on how to use `data.fetchMore`? Using `GET_FILTERS` and `GET_POSTS` queries, where `GET_POSTS` takes a variable `filters`, with `compose` and `graphql` rendering arbitrary component `Posts`?

Comment: I found many good inspirations in [apollo-universal-starter-kit](https://github.com/sysgears/apollo-universal-starter-kit/blob/56638f226abe0afefba333600e92784d10bb00ca/packages/client/src/modules/post/containers/Post.jsx)